# Electroweak contribution to the anomalous magnetic dipole moment of the muon

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, magnetic-moment, electroweak

There are 3 diagrams that contributes to the anomalous magnetic moment of the muon (in unitary gauge):

[image: Electroweak contribution in unitary gauge]

The $Z$-contribution is gauge invariant, so we can focus on diagram (i)

The problem is that when I try to calculate diagram (i), I found:

$$F_2(q^2) \sim \int d^4l \ \frac{l^2}{(l^2-\Delta)^3}$$

which diverges.

Doing the same calculation in the $R_{\xi}$ gauge is possible to prove that the result is in fact gauge invariant,
so we can choose $\xi = 1$ to get the result given in [R. Jackiw, S. Weinberg, Phys. Rev. D 5 (1972)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.5.2396).

Do I need to add counterterms to fix the calculation done in unitary gauge?
(I heard that by adding counterterms, $F_2$ should not change, which means its not going to solve the problem.)

A similar problem occurs with the $W$ contribution.

What am I missing?